# AngularJS expressions stop working when adding controller to body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've tried building a simple Todo List app using [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), however I've experienced a problem.
Whenever I add the `ng-controller` and `ng-reapeat` directives to my code, AngularJS expressions stop working.
Here is my code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="starter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">ToDo</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="todo in TodoList">{{todo.name}}</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.TodoList = [
    {name: "Item 1"},
    {name: "Item 2"}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the core module of your app in `app.js` as:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
```

However, in your html, you're defining your app as:

```
<html ng-app="starter">
```

In your `ng-app` attribute, you're defining this app as an Angular app, and you're referencing a module which does not exist (`starter`). You need to specify which Angular module to use, which in your app.js at the moment is `ionicApp`. So try renaming `starter` to `ionicApp`, or the otherway around, as long as they have matching names.